List TPM key name
I used the tpm2-openssl https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-openssl/tree/master  with openssl to generate a CSR for signing. The below command worked fine
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -out testcert.csr -subj "/C=US/ST=NJ/L=Test/O=c/OU=etes/CN=testcert" -provider tpm2

I was able to sign the CSR with my private PKI as well. The next step is to reference the private key in tpm and the signed public cert for the Nginx to use as a proxy for TLS. Not sure what the key name for the private key in tpm is as there seems to not an easier way to just list the key names.
